# Git credentials on vs code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, credentials

I'm having an issue with an account associated with a deleted email. This account's credentials are associated with my VS Code and I can't delete them. When I try to upload my project to a repository in my current account, an error occurs because my old account does not have access to this repository. I also cannot access my old account, because a verification is required (a pin number is sent to my email that no longer exists). How can I delete these credentials?

`remote: Permission to new-account/repository.git denied to old-account.`

`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/new-account/repository.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

I tried deleting my credentials directly on my pc, in the credential manager, and also tried, in VS Code, to use the following:

```
git config --local user.name "new-username"
git config --local user.email "new@email"
```

didn't work :(